# Vertical fade to transparency on img using CSS - Browser Compatible

Tags: css, html, compression, transparency

I am having issues with web design as image compression is an important factor, I have taken the photography for the website myself and opted to add a vertical gradient on the image banner which fades to transparency (in image post-processing). The issue is that in order to show the transparency I'm having to save the file as a type .png, but with png compression I am only able to get the image down to 1.5mb, which is not ideal at all...The only work around I can think would be to implement the fade on the image in CSS, but I need something thats browser compatible (exceptions for IE..). I haven't been able to find anything for this. Is there any CSS styling anyone knows of to accomplish this so that I can save the image as a jpeg. The desired outcome is below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a div, place it over the image and give it a gradient:

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.gradient {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgb(255, 255, 255));
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Live preview: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/numdj35u/)